# Unlocking LOCK object in Oracle

Tags: oracle, locking

I have placed a lock on table `my_table` using the following statement :

```
LOCK TABLE my_table IN EXCLUSIVE MODE;
```

How do I release this `lock` from `my_table`?

Answer (score 1):

Commit. Or rollback.

(some more letters here as the above isn't long enough)

Comment: Can we use COMMIT or ROLLBACK to release table level lock?

Comment: Didn't I just say that?

Comment: I need to test that.

Comment: Sure, why not; feel free to COMMIT any time you find appropriate.

Comment: Littlefoot is right. Test with at least two sessions.